# How to store variable in session codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-variables

I would like to store the variable in the session currently i am tryin like this but not working.

In Controller

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['myvar']='myvalue';
?>
```

Comment: What does 'not working' means? How do you try to retireve it later?

Comment: yes. i am trying to used it in some other pages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple :

First, load this library

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Then, to add some informations in session :

```
$newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Next, if you want to get values :

```
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
```

And to remove :

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('some_name');
```

A simple search "codeigniter session" could have help you ...

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Don't forget to upvote and mark as solved if you find this useful :)

Answer (score 16):

You don't have to set the session the PHP way.

CodeIgnter has its on [**Session Class**](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html)

Load the session library:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

To set session data:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');
```

To retrieve session data:

```
$this->session->userdata('some_name');
```

To remove session data:

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('some_name');
```

Answer (score 2):

I consider storing my session data in a controller. So this is how you should go about storing and retrieving session data

1.Use autoload in your config.php files. It saves you time and load time

> autoload['libraries'] = ('session);

2.In your controller.php create an array to store your session data.

> $new_data = array( 'username' => 'martin', 
>                      'email' => 'someone@martin.com', 
>                      'user_logged => TRUE );
>
> $this->session->set_userdata($new_data);

3. Then this is how to call your session data(create a variable and assign it the value of one of the session data you need):

> $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

For further reference visit codeigniter [user_guide/sessions](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 1):

### Codeigniter

set in session

```
$newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

retrieve from session

```
$this->session->userdata('username');
```