# how to store id or any value in session variable and call session in all pages using ci?

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller: test.php

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Test extends CI_Controller 
    {
        function __construct() 
        {
            parent :: __construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'captcha', 'email'));
            $this->load->model('Fetch_data');
        }
        public function student()
        {
            $this->load->view('student-dashboard/index');
        }
    }
```

view: login.php

```
<?php
    if($this->input->post('login'))
    { 
        $email2 = $this->input->post('email2');
        $password2 = $this->input->post('password2');

        $this->db->select('email,password');
        $this->db->from('students');
        $where = "email='$email2' and password = '$password2'";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $num = $query->num_rows();
        if($num >'0')
        {
            $this->db->select('email,password,student_id');
            $this->db->from('students');
            $where = "email='$email2' and password = '$password2'";
            $this->db->where($where);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result_array();

            $data['student_id'] = $this->session->set_userdata('student_id',$result);
            if($result == true)
            {
                redirect('/test/student', $data);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p style='color: red;font-weight: bold;'>Wrong email id or password! </p>";
        }
    }
?>
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="email2" id="email2" placeholder="Enter Your Email" class="text-line"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Enter Your Password" class="text-line"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-warning"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am new in codeigniter. In this code I am creating login form and it work perfectly. Now, I want to store student_id into session variable through which I can give welcome message on my all pages. So, How can I do this ? please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078716/how-to-store-variable-in-session-codeignitor

Comment: but I am also using userdata but when I use print_r($data['student_id']); it show nothing

Comment: can any body help me please

Comment: try with the link i was gave you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store variable in session codeignitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078716/how-to-store-variable-in-session-codeignitor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
$data['student_id'] = $this->session->set_userdata('student_id',$result['student_id']);
```

to this one:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('student_id',$result['student_id']);
$data['student_id'] = $this->session->userdata('student_id');
```

You have to load `session` also

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Comment: how can I call $student_id in another page @poonam

Comment: Pass the `$data` in view. Use `$student_id` direct.

Comment: it showing error  Filename: student-dashboard/index.php
Line Number: 2
Backtrace:
File: /var/www/html/collegescan_ci/application/views/student-dashboard/index.php
Line: 2
Function: _error_handler
File: /var/www/html/collegescan_ci/application/controllers/Test.php
Line: 711
Function: view
File: /var/www/html/collegescan_ci/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: You are redirecting the page with `redirect('/test/student', $data);`.

Comment: You should get the session data in `/test/student`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148281/discussion-between-omkara-and-poonam).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add/create session data :

```html
$data = array(
        'student_id'  => 'id',
        'name'     => 'name',
        <!-- Your parameters -->
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

In order to use Session library you should load it in the constructor method in each controller you need it as :

```html
$this->load->library('session');
```

By doing this, session variables will be available for all views you are loading in this controller.
In your view you can give welcome message with :

```html
<?php echo "Hello ".$this->session->userdata('student_id');?>
```

Anyway, i suggest you to move your php code from the view (login.php) to the controller (test.php). It eases your work

Answer (score 0):

you can stored the data as array like this change field as you want

```
$session = array(
                    'isLoggedIn' => TRUE,
                    'username' => $result['username'],
                    'roleid' => $result['roleid'],
                    'id' => $result['id']
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($session);
```

and retrive data like

```
$roleid=$this->session->userdata('roleid');
```